# How to enable CSS editor features in VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, css-editor

I seem to be missing all of the cool CSS editor features that were in VS 2012 RC. For example, the color picker. Is it because I am using the evaluation version? Or is there a switch to turn them on in the release?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the "Web Essentials 2012" extension from "Tools > Extensions and Updates > Online > Visual Studio Gallery."  A restart of VS2012 will be required.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok I see now. Weird I had to disable resharper 7 in order to get the color picker.

Comment: Yeah, Resharper still to date of this comment tries to replace the color picker with its own. I considered removing R# intellisense for CSS entirely.

Comment: So any ideas if (as of March 2013) it's possible to keep using Resharper but just turn off it's color picker so the Web Essentials color picker can kick in?